# Starting pyspark-shell gives env jupyter no such file error in mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I've followed this guide to setup my pyspark instead of pip3 used brew to install spark on my mac machine and https://medium.com/swlh/pyspark-on-macos-installation-and-use-31f84ca61400 and everything went good I was able to open pyspark shell and run the spark code.

Later when I figured out my default shell is zsh moved everything from bash to zsh and tried to execute pyspark command and but got error env: jupyter: No such file or directory. How is jupyter required for pyspark and why?

So configured the

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=path/to/jupyter
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook.
```

Then it started to launch the Jupyter notebook instead of pyspark shell.

How can we run pyspark shell without any jupyter notebook? and why does spark need jupyter to run in shell mode?

> Below is my current .zshrc

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
alias python='python3'
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able solve this issue by making the below changes to my ~/.zshrc and it started running good.

```
alias python='python3'
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3

export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.7
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python:$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
```